# Using LiveConnect, calling a function doesn't pass the strings properly

Tags: java, javascript, liveconnect

I've got a little problem with calling javascript functions via liveconnect on java. It's not calling the function with the proper items, as the Safari console just classes the objects as "RuntimeObject" but in javascript i use:

```
chat.call("message", new String[]{ action, data });
```

arguments action and data are not being forwarded as proper strings, even though they are referenced as Java Strings. Is there something obvious and silly I'm missing out here?

kenny

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this buy in the javascript adding:

```
action = action + "";
data = data + "";
```

and it casts the objects to strings, so it now works :)